# Apple Watch: WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success) not working

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-3

I try to let the  Watch vibrate from within my code:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
```

but nothing happens. I also tried to ensure to be on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
}
```

still nothing. Am I missing something here? I expected it to be an easy task, but I fail completely...

Comment: Try this.. WKInterfaceDevice().playHaptic(.success)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your watch app is not in the active state? Citing the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play):

> This method has no effect when called while your shared WKExtension object's applicationState property is either background or inactive. By default, you cannot play haptic feedback in the background. The only exception are apps with an active workout session.

So, unless you have a running HKWorkoutSession, if your app is in background you're not allowed to play haptic.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of HKWorkoutSession you could use [WKExtendedRuntimeSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions?language=objc) to support running the app in the background so sounds and haptics work. This needs to be done using either the Physical therapy or Smart alarm session type.

Answer (score 0):

Check Haptic Alerts are on in device settings!

**Settings -> Sounds and Haptics**

[image]